# Reading JSON on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, web-services

I'm trying to read json from my Web Service.

I get an error when I try to read teh file form the Web Service.

[image]

This is my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ShowServers', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/espaidiscos/WebService/ws.php/servidors').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.servers = data;
      console.log("work");
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
      console.log("don't work");
    });
});
```

The html:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <header>
        <script src="./assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="ShowServers">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="server in servers">
                    {{ server.nom }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--<div ng-controller="GreetingController">
            {{ greeting }}
        </div>-->
    </body>
    <!--<script src="./assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="./assets/js/controller.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>-->
</html>
```

I can't get any value on the browser. I'm very newbie, any help would be grateful.

Edit:

This is What I get form the Web Service on this URL:

```
{"servers": [{"idServidors":"1","nom":"file01","ip":"10.0.0.170"},{"idServidors":"2","nom":"dc","ip":"10.0.0.5"}]}
```

Edit v2:

I tryied with SoapUI and this is what my web service is returning me:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <title/>
   </head>
   <body>{"servers": [{"idServidors":"1","nom":"file01","ip":"10.0.0.170"},{"idServidors":"2","nom":"dc","ip":"10.0.0.5"}]}</body>
</html>
```

Can the problem comes from here? Don't should be a simple json without body tag and other stuff?

EDIT v3:

Now my web service is working fine and returns a truly json response. I don't get any error on the js chrome console.

This is how my html and angular looks now:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <header>
        <script src="./assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="ShowServers">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="server in servers">
                    {{ server.nom }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--<div ng-controller="GreetingController">
            {{ greeting }}
        </div>-->
    </body>
    <!--<script src="./assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="./assets/js/controller.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>-->
</html>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    $http.get('http://localhost/espaidiscos/WebService/ws.php/servidors').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.servers = data;
      console.log(data);
      console.log(status);
      console.log(headers);
      console.log(config);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
      console.log("Error");
    });
});
```

SOLVED:

I copyed the example on w3schools site: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

```
<script>
var MyApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
MyApp.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost/espaidiscos/WebService/ws.php/servidors")
    .then(function(response) {
                  $scope.servers= response.data.servers;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: just give data.servers in the success callback.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like 2 things could be happening. The first is the variable servers isn't instantiated when the ng-repeat runs.

The second is servers doesn't actually have a nom attribute.

```
$scope.servers = [];
//HTTP Request
```

Also, print out the servers variable from request to make sure you are getting what you think.

EDIT:

You are making $scope.servers equal to the servers object. You should make it equal data.servers. ng-repeat is only going to work over an array.

EDIT2:

If you're getting an error in the error callback, you must print out the servers response to try and debug it. Without seeing this information I can only guess at what's happening. If you can post the URL in your browser and get JSON fine, but when you try it from javascript, you get an error, then it might have something to do with the response-type. The browser will use a response-type of HTML where from Angular I believe the response-type will be JSON by default. Your server might error out if it doesn't know how to handle the latter.

EDIT3

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ShowServers',function($scope,$http,GetServers){
 GetServers.simGetServers($scope);
});

myApp.factory('GetServers', function($http,$timeout){
 var simGetServers = function(scope){
  $timeout(function(){
   data = {"servers": [{"idServidors":"1","nom":"file01","ip":"10.0.0.170"},{"idServidors":"2","nom":"dc","ip":"10.0.0.5"}]}
   scope.servers = data.servers;
  },200)
 }; 
 var getServers = function(scope){
  $http.get('http://localhost/espaidiscos/WebService/ws.php/servidors').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      scope.servers = data.servers;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
    });
 };
 return {
  getServers: function(scope){
   getServers(scope);
  },
  simGetServers: function(scope){
   simGetServers(scope);
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<html>
 <header>
  <title>StackOverflow Question Response</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 </header>
 <body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ShowServers">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="server in servers" ng-cloak>
     {{ server.nom }}
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

You put your script outside of the body tag!

Comment: I changed but still don't work: success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.servers = data.servers;
      console.log("work");
    }).

Comment: data.servers is correct but also print out $scope.servers inside of console.log to make sure you are getting an array back. You may need to follow my other advice and instantiate $scope.servers before making the HTML request. Post your new error when you get it

Comment: I tryed and returned 'undefined'

Comment: If its printing undefined in the success callback of the request then you aren't getting any data back. console.log data to examine what its sending. What I think is happening is the response is composed differently compared to when you check it with your browser. Perhaps you aren't including the response type = json? etc

Comment: I've been trynig and the console.log message comes from the error callback. But I don't see the error anyway

Comment: You have to print out the error args to see why the server is sending back an error. Print out data, headers etc.

Comment: I tryed doing the request form SoapUI and the Web Service is not  responding with a json. I see a json on the browser but is html only. I'm dealing with that now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For a quick fix, you can change the response type in Angular to HTML. Although in the long run you probably want to fix that on the server. If you want to see if your angular works correctly assuming a correct server, you can simulate a request with a timeout. If I fixed your problem be sure to accept my answer! Good luck

Comment: I will Try it @CleoR. If works be sure I will accept it

Comment: I've made changes on my Web Service. One of the problem was caused because the web service was returning json but on the header was saying html. I've changed this and now returns a truly json. But angular doesn't work appropriately yet.

Comment: I thought it was something of that sort. Did you instantiate $scope.servers = [] before you make the HTTP request?

Comment: You removed your controller too, that needs to be put like you had it before

Comment: You also typically put the ng-app on the body, not the html

Comment: I tryed instantiating $scope.servers=[] and doesn't work

Comment: Im gonna write your code out and post it when I get back from my exam at 6. If you figure it out before than be sure to post your solution. Good luck!

Comment: Finally I did it work. On the angular side I copyed the example on w3schools site. var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function(response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});

Comment: Nice! I wrote the code out above if you still want it. It looks like you put your script tag in the wrong place too

Answer (score 1):

The error you show from your web browser's console implies that the server is not providing a JSON object. Check your web service to make sure that it is proving the object the way you expect.

Comment: If i go to the URL I get this: {"servers": [{"idServidors":"1","nom":"file01","ip":"10.0.0.170"},{"idServidors":"2","nom":"dc","ip":"10.0.0.5"}]} I validated with an online JSON validator and looks fine.

Comment: You have to make $scope.servers = to data.servers

Comment: I tryed this but doesn't see any changes